# Alerting string using document.getElementById().innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to alert a string, using document.getElementById().innerHTML, but it's alerting the code of the whole page, instead of the string inside the div. I need it to alert '121'. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function getUrban(pageNum, stopAt, gotoUrl) {

var currentPage = "currentPage";
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: gotoUrl,
           data: { pageNum : pageNum },
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert("error");},
           success:function(data) {
           document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data;
           currentPage = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
           },
           complete:function(data) {
           alert(currentPage);
           } //end of complete:function(data)

      });

} //end of function getUrban(pageNum)

getUrban(121,422,"test.php");

</script>

<div id = "output"></div>
```

**Output in Alert:**

```
The full code of the whole page, plus some more code about setting the width.
```

**Output in div with id 'output':**

```
121
```

**Need Alert:**

```
121
```

**test.php**

```
$pageNum = $_POST['pageNum'];
echo $pageNum;
```

Comment: I don't see an alert anywhere in your code.  But you are using jQuery, why not get the element by `$('#output').html();`?

Comment: @AndrewCoder alert is under complete

Comment: @AndrewCoder Also, using what you suggested does the same thing. I just tried it.

Comment: Ah duh.  My mistake I missed it(you need more tabbing in your code hierarchy :) ).  It's a little confusing what you are doing with the `currentpage` var.  You want it to alert '121' but you are pulling the html from an empty div and alerting that.  Maybe I'm confused.

Comment: Is your markup similar to "<html><body>121</body></html>"?

Comment: Also not sure why the alert is in "complete" function instead of success function.

Comment: @AndrewCoder It's not empty. You see the line before setting the currentPage var? document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data;

Comment: @Vohuman You mean what it's alerting?

Comment: Yes I do.  Try updating those two lines to this:
`document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data;`
`currentPage = data;`
No point in pulling data into a variable that already exists in the variable.

Comment: is currentPage supposed to contain HTML, or the page number?  Looks like it's getting HTML as it is now.

Comment: ie `alert(pageNum)` in the function would get the '121' as declared in your JS call of the function.

Comment: @AndrewCoder data is an ajax object. It will alert 'object' if you do that. I also tried json.stringify but that also alert the code of the whole page.

Comment: Yes it's an ajax object, but it should return the output of whatever page was called with ajax.  I think you are just alerting the wrong JS var.

Comment: Yes. You are alerting html contents of that specific element. If the content is "<b>121</b> whatever...", according to your code browser should simply alert that content. What do you expect? Do you want to get the _textContent_ of the element? Or do you want to alert the first parameter of the `getUrban` function?

Comment: @AndrewCoder That's the code on the whole page, so I don't see how it's possible I'm echoing the wrong JS var, since there aren't any JS var left on the page.

Comment: @Vohuman I want to alert the data from the ajax call, which is '121' because that's the only thing I'd echoed in the php ajax call page. Instead it echoing the code of the whole page of the current page.

Comment: To confirm, do you want it alerting the '121' because you specified it in your function call `getUrban(121,422,"test.php");`? or do you want it alerting '121' because that's what `url: gotoUrl,` spit back via ajax?

Comment: Well, logically that should not happen. It would be helpful if you could reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Vohuman Um. How would I reproduce the problem? You mean like make a snippet or something?

Comment: @AndrewCoder the second one.

Comment: Then we need to see the code for the page that ajax is calling to try and help.

Comment: @AndrewCoder see above.

Comment: can you add `print_r($_POST);` to your test.php and post the output here?

Comment: @AndrewCoder I'm an idiot. In test.php I had an include file, that I forgot about. There probably was some echo statements in the include file. That include file has a list of functions that I use all the time, so i forgot about it.

Comment: Ahh lol.  More code(even if sanitized) would have helped figure that out earlier :)

Comment: Nice, we have spent 35 minutes for debugging this :)

Comment: @AndrewCoder Sorry to you too. Thanks for you guys help.

Comment: No need to say sorry man. The good news is the problem has been solved.

Comment: Agreed.  No worries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery to do the ajax why don't you use jquery for everything else also.

```
$('#output').text();
```

Will get only the text inside the div. Not the html elements as well.

It drives me crazy to see people using jQuery and have document.getElementById('id') in their code. You do realize that $('id') will get the same element but with jQuery wrapper so you can use jQuery functions on it. And it's so much shorter to type.

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 

function getUrban(pageNum, stopAt, gotoUrl) {

$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: gotoUrl,
           data: { pageNum : pageNum },
           error: function(xhr,status,error){alert("error");},
           success:function(data) {
               $("#output").html(data);
           },
           complete:function(data) {
               alert($('#output').text());
           } //end of complete:function(data)

      });

} //end of function getUrban(pageNum)

getUrban(121,422,"test.php");

</script>

<div id = "output"></div>
```

Comment: What is being loaded into <div id="output"></div> is it just text or are you filling it with an entire html document? can you post what's being loaded here?

Comment: The `data` object in the ajax call is the rendered html or whatever the other code we can't see does.  We don't know if thats outputting a webpage, or simply the number 121.

Comment: @GreggDuncan It's just the number 121.

Comment: Are you sure that's what's being loaded. Try doing an alert(data); inside your success function. Because if it's just loading the number 121 inside the  output div then alert($('#output').text()); will alert the number 121. just like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zoam5mds/